# Why is mac process "Wi-Fi" using 500mb of RAM?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, memory

Thanks to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/879763/what-is-mac-process-wi-fi), I now understand the existence of the "Wi-Fi" process running in the background on my mac.

But why does it require 500+ MB of RAM when neither the menu item nor any dialogues are open?

[image: Screenshot of activity monitor]

When I quit it using activity monitor, it reappears and only uses 8 MB for a while. But after a couple hours, it is back to using more RAM than Google Chrome.

I am running macOS 10.14 on an early 2015 macBook pro.

Comment: idk the answer & my WiFi is using only a few MB after a whole day - but your comparison to Chrome is out by a long way - you need to add all the Helpers too; so 1700MB from what can be seen in that small image.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to AskDifferent.

Comment: I have the same problem, though for me the process is using 4.32 GB. I agree with @MMB though that this should be in AskDifferent.

Comment: This question has also been asked several times on apple.SE, but with no resolution: [340286](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340286/wi-fi-taking-up-lot-of-memory), [340842](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340842/why-is-wifi-using-a-lot-of-ram), [349250](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349250/why-is-my-wi-fi-process-eating-2gb-memory), [362861](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362861/why-is-my-wi-fi-process-using-3gb-of-memory).